# UISegmentedControl.enabled = NO doesn't dim it

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` in a `UIView` in my popover that I want to disable in some cases. The segmented control is set up with Interface Builder in a nib file. Its IB "Enabled" checkbook is checked.

To disable it, I wrote:

```
self.segmentedControl.enabled = NO;  // or YES when I want it enabled
```

Which works to the extent that from there on the segmented control doesn't react to touch events.

However, there is no graphic feedback whatsoever. I would like the  segmented control to dim (gray out) when it's disabled. I tried to set its `highlighted` property to `NO` as well, with no effect.

This should be possible as disabling the `UISegmentedControl` with Interface Builder produces the dimming effect that I want.

However, if I do that, my code then cannot re-enable it:

```
self.segmentedControl.enabled = YES;
```

will not make it enabled: even though it will start accepting touch events again, it will stay dimmed.

It's as if the IB "enabled" check box controller two properties: `enabled` and `dimmed`. But what is this `dimmed` property that I can't find?

What did I miss?

This is in the 4.3 iPad simulator.

(note that I am talking about the whole control, not its individual segments).

**Edit:** I investigated a bit further and I found out that disabling the segmented control in IB also sets its `alpha` property to 0.5.

When adding:

```
self.segmentedControl.alpha = 0.5; // or 1.0 if enabled
```

My app now seems to behave normally.

Am I right to think that setting the `enabled` property should also take care of the screen appearance?

Comment: Did you thought about changing the alpha of the segmented control?

Comment: Lol, you thought about it before me!

Comment: I don't think the `enabled` property should take care of the screen appearance. You should decide what happens on the screen.

Comment: as long as I can remember, disabling a button used to dim it too.

Answer (score 8):

I found that this works for each segment:

```
[self.segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

The effect is subtle, but it does grey it out. To do all segments:

```
for(int index=0; index<self.segmentedControl.numberOfSegments; index++)
{
    [self.segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I find this even more cumbersome than simply setting the segmented control's alpha property...

Comment: it is a bit involved, but I guess it depends on how "correct" you want to be :)

Answer (score 5):

I ran across the exact same problem, with an interesting twist. The interface behaves as you describe it on an iPad running iOS 4.3. However, the segmented control DOES dim in an iPad running iOS 5.0. So, my assumption is that this is a bug that was fixed by Apple in iOS 5.

Comment: haha! interesting observation. Thanks. So Apple agreed with me that disabling a control should also take care of the screen appearance.